# Order Isomorphisms of $\aleph_2$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

Here's what I already know:

1. We say that an **infinite** well-ordered set $A$ is *order isomorphic* to the set of natural numbers $\aleph_0$ if every initial segment of $A$ is **finite**.
2. We say that an **uncountable** well-ordered set $B$ is *order isomorphic* to the set $\aleph_1$ if every intial segment of $B$ is **countable**.

Now I am looking to fill in the following blanks for $\aleph_2$:

We say that a ________ well-ordered set $C$ is *order isomorphic* to the set $\aleph_2$ if every intial segment of $C$ is _________.

The motivation here is that every cardinal is really a special sort of ordinal. I want to know what makes $\aleph_2$ different from its preceding cardinals, in a general sense.

The first blank will need to be a descriptor for all sets with cardinality $\geq \aleph_2$.
The second blank will need to describe any sort of set with cardinality $<\aleph_2$. These terms may not necissarily exist, but a mathematical definition would work just as well.

Comment: Blank 1 = still "uncountable". Blank 2 = "of cardinality aleph1".

Comment: @ziggurism This is false. The set {0,1,2,3} is an initial segment of $\aleph_0$ and by extension of $\aleph_2$, but the set {0,1,2,3} is countable.

Comment: It's worth noting that $\aleph_2$ can consistently have more natural descriptions. E.g. it is consistent that $\aleph_2=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ and hence we can use the phrase "of cardinality continuum" instead; in fact, $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ isn't just *consistent*, it is a *direct consequence* of [a natural (in many set theorists' opinions, at least) set-theoretic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom). However, there is no specific term which *definitionally* means "of cardinality $\aleph_2$" (or similar).

Comment: @EshinGriffith oops. "of cardinality aleph1 or less".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you won't be too happy with this example, but there's really nothing clever to do here:

> Every well-ordering of cardinality at least $\aleph_2$ *(or if you prefer, cardinality $>\aleph_1$)* is isomorphic to $\aleph_2$ iff all of its proper initial segments have cardinality $\le\aleph_1$.

In general, suppose $\kappa$ is a cardinal; then a well-ordering $L$ of cardinality $\ge\kappa$ is order-isomorphic to $\kappa$ iff every proper initial segment of $L$ has cardinality $<\kappa$.

*Note that "cardinality $<\aleph_1$" means "countable" and "cardinality $\ge\aleph_0$" means "infinite," so the example "an uncountable well-ordering is isomorphic to $\aleph_1$ iff every proper initial segment is countable" is indeed a special case of the above. I think it's important to note that **there are no specific term** for properties such as "cardinality $\ge\aleph_2$" or "cardinality $\le\aleph_1$" analogous to "uncountable" and "countable."*

In the case of a successor cardinal $\kappa=\lambda^+$, this amounts to: a well-ordering $L$ of cardinality $>\lambda$ is order-isomorphic to $\kappa$ iff every proper initial segment of $L$ has cardinality $\le\lambda$.

---

The point is that **cardinals are initial ordinals**: an ordinal $\alpha$ is an initial ordinal iff there is no bijection between $\alpha$ and any $\beta<\alpha$. Cardinals, set-theoretically, are just initial ordinals; the use of the word "cardinal" is merely suggestive of the context.

If $\alpha$ is an initial ordinal, then by definition any proper initial segment of $\alpha$ is of cardinality $<\alpha$ - remember that a proper initial segment of any ordinal $\gamma$ is in fact an ordinal smaller than $\gamma$ *(downwards-closed sets of ordinals are ordinals!)*.